# Android studio HERE MAP SDK MAP polyLine error

Tags: android, here-api, polyline

```
ArrayList<GeoCoordinates> coordinates = new ArrayList<>();
coordinates.add(new GeoCoordinates(52.53032, 13.37409));
coordinates.add(new GeoCoordinates(52.5309, 13.3946));
coordinates.add(new GeoCoordinates(52.53894, 13.39194));
coordinates.add(new GeoCoordinates(52.54014, 13.37958));
GeoPolyline geoPolyline;

try {
    geoPolyline = new GeoPolyline(coordinates);
} catch (InstantiationErrorException e) {
  geoPolyline = null;
}

float widthInPixels = 20;
Color lineColor = new Color((short) 0x00, (short) 0x90, (short) 0x8A, (short) 0xA0);
MapPolyline mapPolyline = new MapPolyline(geoPolyline, widthInPixels, lineColor);
```

I have the above code to make `MapPolyline` but for some reason it is not allowing me to use the `MapPolyline` function.

**I am getting this error:**

> MapPolyline(com.here.sdk.core.GeoPolyline,
> com.here.sdk.mapviewlite.MapPolylineStyle)' in
> 'com.here.sdk.mapviewlite.MapPolyline' cannot be applied to
> '(com.here.sdk.core.GeoPolyline, float, com.here.sdk.core.Color)'.

These are my imports

```
import com.here.sdk.core.GeoCoordinates;
import com.here.sdk.core.GeoPolyline;
import com.here.sdk.core.errors.InstantiationErrorException;
import com.here.sdk.mapviewlite.MapPolyline;
```

Any Help will be appreciated, thanks

All the other package or function i can access in the com.here.sdk.core

Answer (score 1):

From the error reported it seems that `MapPolyline()` constructor does not accept a float as second parameter `widthInPixels` in your case... you have to define a `MapPolylineStyle`:

```
MapPolylineStyle mapPolylineStyle = new MapPolylineStyle();
    mapPolylineStyle.setWidth(20);
    mapPolylineStyle.setColor(new Color((short) 0x00, (short) 0x90, (short) 0x8A, (short) 0xA0));
    MapPolyline mapPolyline = new MapPolyline(geoPolyline, mapPolylineStyle);
```

as suggested [here](https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-sdk-lite/4.2.0.0/dev_guide/topics/map-items-lite.html)

Answer (score 0):

This should also work:

```
float widthInPixels = 20;
Color lineColor = Color.valueOf(0, 0.56f, 0.54f, 0.63f); // RGBA
MapPolyline mapPolyline = new MapPolyline(geoPolyline, widthInPixels, lineColor);
```

See also this [example app](https://github.com/heremaps/here-sdk-examples/blob/d1baba6878ea3dd89c778dadaa7be74938d4564e/examples/latest/navigate/android/MapItems/app/src/main/java/com/here/mapitems/MapObjectsExample.java#L113) to try it out.